# Checking where 1 occurs in a Binary Number

Tags: python, binary, append

I have a binary number : 1010

I need to first append it to 0000000001010 ( size 13 )
and then calculate in which position "1" occurs

I get different binary numbers each time so next time it may be 100000000 which means i just need to append "0000" and then calculate which bit has 1 in it.

I am not able to figure out how to append in python.

I have a basic convention that bit 0 does something ... bit 12 does "xyz" and its in Little Indian format hence I need to make the length of any binary number i get equal to 12 before I start processing which bit is active ( ie has 1 )

Please help.. It has to be done in python only, since the rest of the code is in python...

Programming novice. Thanks.

Comment: Your question will likely get downvoted unless you edit it to add some more info like how are numbers represented, as integers, strings etc.  What do you mean by append? To the end or to the front?  Showing the expected output for each would help.  Also, what if there is more than one '1'?

Comment: How are your binary numbers represented? E.g. as integers, as a string, or a list?

Comment: You may want to look at [`bitstring`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring), which lets you mix and match representations, and do numeric, bitmask, and string-style operations on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the padding using the following string formatting

```
yourBinNumber = 1010
paddedString = "%013d" % yourBinNumber
```

Then find out the position of 1 as follows

```
paddedString.index("1")
```

More information about Python String formatting can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I think you actually figured out what was being asked. I bet it will be hard for noobs to understand why it works.  It is very difficult to find info and examples on the % operator in relation to strings.

Answer (score 0):

The naive case;

Assuming that your start numbers always begin with '1', and you always create a string with binary representation with 13 digits then the result is always

```
 13 - len(initialNumber)
```

e.g;

```
 = 13 - len("1010") 

 = 13 - 4

 = 9 

 Result:  0000000001010
          ^^^^^^^^^X^^^
 Indices: 0123456789...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to run a different function for each 1 in a binary string, you can do something like this:

```
def fun0():
    print('fun0');

def fun1():
    print('fun1');

... 

def fun12():
    print('fun12');

funs = [fun0, fun1, ... , fun12]

# ass x is binary string
x = '1010'

# convert to integer
xi = int(x,2)
for i in range(0,13):
    if(xi & (1 << i) != 0):
        funs[i]()
```

outputs:

> > > ```
> > > fun1
> > > fun3
> > > ```